# На чем делать графики в Web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, reactjs, d3.js

Есть ли смысл смысл использовать фрэймворки ReactJS, NodeJS или d3 Для отрисовки графиков? в графиках будет до 10000 точек, масштабирование, пролистывание. Не упадет ли производительность? Сильно ли это поможет в написании кода? Или лучше писать на чистом javascript? Нужно сделать наподобие вот этого яндексовского https://news.yandex.ru/quotes/1.html с таким же управлением масштаба.

Comment: Если у вас не суперкастомный график, лучше воспользуйтесь готовым решением

Comment: Я бы для начала попробовал использовать [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), перед тем, как городить свой велосипед. Линейные диаграммы с информацией о точках там по крайней мере есть.

Comment: Если что, приведённый яндексовский график - это svg. Нужно понимать, что вы хотите получить в итоге. SVG даёт больший спектр возможностей, но тяжелее. Canvas легче, но и сделать на нём можно не всё, что можно сделать в SVG. Более того, упомянутый зум - это плохая идея в случае с canvas. Однако, я бы присоединился в комментарию @AlexKrass и попробовал бы сначала ChartJS

Comment: попробуйте, - http://recharts.org/#/en-US/ и напишите упал или нет. очень интересно. до 1000 точек проблем не было.

Comment: Я бы написал свою функцию по сбору точек => в массив, потом от рисовал циклом все линии по массиву точек + масштабирование повесил бы на скейл/скролл и пролистывание делил условно максимум/минимум слайдов + отображение точек, если сделать с умом все будет гуд

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mbfmw1se/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas - идеальное решение для тебя. График можно представить в виде двухмерного массива хранящего данные про весь график в формате `[[x], [y]]`, дальше сверять активную (просматриваемую на данный момент) позицию графика, округлять полученные координаты и рисовать точки из массива в диапазоне текущая позиция + размер экрана/толщину линии или другую характеристику, участвующую в отрисовке.

Удобно, оптимизация на высоте, работает.

Нужно будет только создать редактор для создания графиков, но по моей схеме и это достаточно просто.

Среди движков можно юзать PIXI или POINT.js (по-моему в нем есть что-то вроде `newRectObject()`, но это не точно)

Answer (score 0):

Упадёт. Рендеринг толстого DOM — дело затратное. Для подобных вещей лучше и оптимальнее всего использовать canvas. Существует много библиотек для создания графов на канвасе.

З.Ы. NodeJS это не фреймворк.

Comment: Это не мешает примеру в вопросе быть сделанным на svg.

Comment: @Qwertiy SVG и React?

Comment: А что не так с реактом?

Comment: @Qwertiy всё хорошо, просто не встречал такую экзотическую связку) Но это интересно